# How to conditionally replace, add or remove object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that I want to either add, remove or replace in an object of arrays based on these three conditions:

1. If the object exists in the array then remove it
2. If the object's `query` property matches with an item in the array then replace it
3. If the object does not exist in the array then add it

I thought it was simple but it has been giving me problems when I test it:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    query: 'mangoes'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    query: "alright"
  }
]
// Should be removed:
const test1 = {
  id: 2,
  query: 'alright'
}

// Should be replaced:
const test2 = {
  id: 3,
  query: 'mangoes'
}

// Should be added
const test3 = {
  id: 4,
  query: 'ok'
}

const toggle = (payload) => {
  const ans = arr

    .filter(obj => obj.id != payload.id) // remove if needed
    .map(obj => obj.query == payload.query ? // replace if needed  
      payload :
      obj
    )
    .concat( // add if needed
      arr.findIndex(obj => obj.id == payload.id) == -1 ?
      payload : []
    )

  console.log(ans)
}

toggle(test1) 
toggle(test2)
toggle(test3)
```

An optimal solution would be if I could implement this with a `Array.reduce` function, or anything else that could work

Playing around with the `.concat()` at the end has only allowed me to accomplish the first two tests instead of getting all three at the same time.

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Comment: There's not really enough information here. What should happen if more than one item matches the `query` property?

Comment: What's the definition of "exists"? Same `id` and same `query` or just same `id`?

Comment: Same `id` and same `query`

Answer (score 2):

It's easier in this case to find the index of the item using the `query` property. If item not found (`-1`), add the payload. If an index is found, slice it out, and then add the item if the 'id' property do not match:

```js
const toggle = payload => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(o => o.query === payload.query) // find index with identical query
  
  if(idx === -1) return [...arr, payload] // if none found add
  
  return [
    ...arr.slice(0, idx),
    ...(payload.id === arr[idx].id ? [] : [payload]), // insert if same id
    ...arr.slice(idx + 1) // remove original

  ]
}

const arr = [{"id":1,"query":"mangoes"},{"id":2,"query":"alright"}]
// Should be removed:
const test1 = { id: 2, query: 'alright' }
// Should be replaced:
const test2 = { id: 3, query: 'mangoes' }
// Should be added
const test3 = { id: 4, query: 'ok' }

console.log(toggle(test1));
console.log(toggle(test2));
console.log(toggle(test3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find the index for removing an object, find the index for updating or add the object.

```js
function update(array, object) {
    var id = array.findIndex(q => ['id', 'query'].every(k => q[k] === object[k])),
        query = array.findIndex(q => q.query === object.query);

    if (id !== -1) return array.splice(id, 1);
    if (query !== -1) return array[query] = object;
    array.push(object);
}

const
    array = [{ id: 1, query: 'mangoes' }, { id: 2, query: "alright" }],
    remove = { id: 2, query: 'alright' },
    replace = { id: 3, query: 'mangoes' },
    add = { id: 4, query: 'ok' };

update(array, remove);
update(array, replace);
update(array, add);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant *a la* cut

try some predicate and if one succeeds abort

here, in the same order, try to remove, else try to replace, or finally try to add

To abort, we may use `some` and return true iff a predicate succeeds

```js
const toggle = (el) => {
  arr.some((o,i) => {
    return o.id == el.id ? arr.splice(i,1):
      o.query == el.query ? arr[i] = el: false
  }) || arr.push(el)
  console.log(arr)
}

const arr = [{
    id: 1,
    query: 'mangoes'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    query: "alright"
  }
]
// Should be removed:
const test1 = {
  id: 2,
  query: 'alright'
}

// Should be replaced:
const test2 = {
  id: 3,
  query: 'mangoes'
}
// Should be added
const test3 = {
  id: 4,
  query: 'ok'
}
toggle(test1)
toggle(test2)
toggle(test3)
```